# Gitlab deploy script - envsubst: command not found

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a gitlab repo with CI/CD pipeline. It has deploy.sh script, which runs smoothly until envsubst command:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
<...>
# deploy via ssh
SSH="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -l $SSH_USER 
$HOST"

echo "create project dir"
$SSH "mkdir -p $PROJECT_ROOT"

echo "create env file"
envsubst < $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME.tmpl.env | $SSH "cat > ${PROJECT_ROOT}/${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}.env"
```

Job fails with error:

```
create env file
./deploy.sh: line 65: envsubst: command not found
```

Headers of '.gitlab-ci.yml' file:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
```

Comment: envsubst is a GNU Coreutils tool.  Images based on Alpine Linux won't usually have that available (in the same way they don't have GNU Bash unless you manually install it).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, '- apk update && apk add gettext' does the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [DavidMaze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) pointed out, I added 'gettext' package to '.gitlab-ci.yml' file:

```
deploy-on-server:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - apk update && apk add bash
    - apk update && apk add gettext
  <...>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the ssh parts of the script?

Comment: Sorry for the long reply, it checks if there is an ssh client on the system ('which ssh-agent ' returns null or binary path) and installs it if necessary. I assume some of gitlab runners  don't have it.